# How come useHistory hook in React is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-hooks

For some reason when I type npm start to launch my web application, apparently there is an error in which the useHistory hook has not been downloaded even if I have installed the latest version of react-router-dom...can someone tell me why?
[This is my screen where I imported useHistory from react-router-dom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yXqC.png)

[here my package.json files say that I have the latest react-router-dom installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkwQE.png)

I tried downloading the latest version of react - but even then it still didn't work..

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory

Answer (score 3):

In react-router-dom v6 useHistory() is replaced by useNavigate().

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/');
```